# Access token limit in docusign (node module)

Tags: docusignapi

I have using docusign node module for using embedded signing flow. Things have been working fine but suddenly we have started seeing errors such as access token limit exceeded.

Here is the error

```
Description: Maximum number of access tokens exceeded.
at /Users/amitagwl/Projects/Personal/support.birdeye.com/node_modules/docusign-node/components/auth.js:105:17
```

Questions:

- In quick look up I found that production accounts have 10 as token limit. Why is that ? If I have exceeded the limit, does it mean I can't use my account any more ?
- Can I reuse existing token ? How do I see my previously created token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application is allowed 10 tokens per authenticated user.  In other words your app can connect to a user's account only 10 times.  The tokens can (and should) be reused.  Typical apps will require only one token for each user - or one token for each account of Send-On-Behalf-Of is used.

In general you should authenticate once, get the token, store that token, and use it for future access to that user's account.  The user may revoke that token at any time so your app should prompt for authentication if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Tokens can be revoked under "connected apps". (Classic experience only).

Comment: To get there: My Preferences > Connected Apps > Manage Apps > Connected Apps tab